# Version ranges in buildout.cfg

Tags: python, buildout

I have a project for which I'd like to maintain the most recent stable version of Django 1.7 (presently at 1.7.1, but that may change).

In `setup.py`, I've specified the version range like this:

```
setup(
    # ...
    install_requires = ['setuptools',
        'django >= 1.7, < 1.8',
    ],
)
```

In `buildout.cfg`, I've specified the same:

```
[versions]
django = >= 1.7, < 1.8
ipython = >= 2.3.1, < 3.0.0
```

For `ipython`, this works great, but unfortunately Django doesn't seem to like it:

```
Got Django 1.7.1.
Uninstalling ipython_section.
Installing python_section.
While:
  Installing python_section.

An internal error occurred due to a bug in either zc.buildout or in a
recipe being used:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 1942, in main
    getattr(buildout, command)(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 622, in install
    installed_files = self[part]._call(recipe.install)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 1366, in _call
    return f()
  File "/home/tk/thunderdome/eggs/zc.recipe.egg-2.0.1-py2.7.egg/zc/recipe/egg/egg.py", line 126, in install
    reqs, ws = self.working_set()
  File "/home/tk/thunderdome/eggs/zc.recipe.egg-2.0.1-py2.7.egg/zc/recipe/egg/egg.py", line 84, in working_set
    allow_hosts=self.allow_hosts)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zc/buildout/easy_install.py", line 812, in install
    return installer.install(specs, working_set)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zc/buildout/easy_install.py", line 644, in install
    requirement = self._constrain(requirement)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zc/buildout/easy_install.py", line 603, in _constrain
    requirement = _constrained_requirement(constraint, requirement)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zc/buildout/easy_install.py", line 1400, in _constrained_requirement
    _constrained_requirement_constraint(constraint, requirement)
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2786, in parse
    reqs = list(parse_requirements(s))
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2714, in parse_requirements
    "version spec")
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2679, in scan_list
    raise ValueError(msg, line, "at", line[p:])
ValueError: ('Expected version spec in', 'django[]>=1.7,,>=1.7,<1.8', 'at', ',>=1.7,<1.8')
```

Why is it failing, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A version spec with `something = <= 1234` is invalid. Both an `=` and a `<=` isn't the right syntax.

I'd treat the problem differently. You use your `setup.py`'s `install_requires` already to restrict buildout a version between 1.7 and 1.8. Buildout will respect that requirement, so you don't need to duplicate it in the buildout config.

What buildout's version pinning is for is exactly that: pinning to **one specific version**. Either you let buildout pick what it wants or you tell it to pick an exact version.

The way I use it is to add a `show-picked-versions = true` option to the `[buildout]` part. Buildout will then print out a list of versions it picked. I then copy/paste that list to `[versions]`. That way you get a repeatable build *and* a nice speed improvement as buildout doesn't have to search pypi for those versions again.